# job title for curriculum vitae

Tags: vocabulary

My friend finished Law school recently and works in her fathers company. She is going to apply for a job somewhere else and needs a good CV. She put in work experience advocate clerk. Is it correct? Or should there be another term.

And one more thing is trainee another correct term to be used on CV?

Comment: I suspect that the usage might be regional. Maybe these two links could help a little: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_clerk, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barristers%27_clerk.

Comment: I agree with @DamkerngT. that this is really a question of local usage, not English-at-large. Each legal culture tends to have its own terms; US usage differs from British, and in the US usage varies from state to state. So you need to tell us a)What duties your friend performed, b) What training she had in those duties, and c) What sort of English the persons who will read this CV read.

Comment: You might also take a look at the Wikipedia articles on [law clerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Clerk) and [paralegal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralegal) and [legal secretary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_secretary).

Comment: In our country after six years of university the Graduate must work in the office for five years under Senior attorney to complete his experience. She was gaining experience under senior attorney, paperwork, going to court, dealing with clients etc.

Comment: @Zana Does this sort of work qualify the graduate herself to become an attorney herself, as an ['articled clerk'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articled_clerk) works towards qualification as a solicitor in the UK? And who will be reading this English CV? American lawyers? British lawyers? -- you see how complex the matter can be!

Comment: The graduate can become an attorney herself after five years of experience. At the moment she can do some administrative work, prepare contracts, deal with clients and she can go to court with small matters. She would like to apply for a job in Slovakia, but maybe for a foreign company, so a native English might read the CV. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

For a British audience it appears that the term should be *trainee solicitor* (*articled clerk* in older usage); Wikipedia describes this role in terms very similar to those in which you describe your friend:

> The training and qualification required to enter the profession by being admitted as a solicitor is regulated by the Solicitors Regulation Authority. There are two graduate routes of entry into the profession. Prospective solicitors holding a qualifying law degree proceed to enroll with the Law Society as a student member and study the Legal Practice Course. Those holding a non-law degree but one which is a "qualifying degree" must in addition have completed a conversion course prior to enrolling on the Legal Practice Course. Once the Legal Practice Course has been completed, the prospective solicitor usually must then undertake two years' apprenticeship, known as a training contract, with a firm entitled to take trainee solicitors.

There is no real equivalent in the US, where “reading for the bar” (that is, serving an apprenticeship under a practicing attorney) has in all but a few states been superseded by earning a *Juris Doctor* (*JD*) from an accredited postgraduate law school, followed by passing the “bar examination” for the appropriate jurisdiction. Law school graduates are often employed by law firms in what amounts to a [paralegal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralegal) capacity while they study for the bar exam, so if your friend were applying for a position with a US law firm she should probably describe herself as a “Law graduate” (or *JB* or *JD* or whatever degree she holds) with *n* years of postgraduate paralegal experience.